# How do I get more raiders at my Nuka-World raider outposts?

Tags: fallout-4

So, I'm playing Fallout 4 as a bad guy and went the Nuka-Cola Overboss route. Now I've got several outposts located in the Commonwealth, each one set up with a Nuka-World radio transmitter, amplifier, pick-me-up station, etc. Each outpost has at least one settlement supplying it as a vassal (usually more) and happiness is up near 100 at each one. When in workshop mode, the top bar is green all across. Getting the raider "settlers" to show up, though, is proving a problem.

With non-raider settlements, once the settlement has food, water, defense, etc., settlers come pouring in fairly quickly. With these outposts, I'm seeing less than six raiders - and that includes the three or four I started with. I get that most, if not all, of the raider settlement system works more-or-less like the normal one, but obviously attracting settlers works differently.

**In Fallout 4, what's the secret to attracting raider 'settlers' to your Nuka-World outposts?**

Comment: When you say raider antenna, do you mean the Nuka World radio transmitter?

Comment: @B.S.Morganstein - yes, the raider version of the recruitment antenna. I'll update it

Comment: And to clarify, are you asking how to improve the chances raiders will attack your outposts?

Comment: @B.S.Morganstein - no, I'm trying to get raiders to settle at my outpost. I tweaked the question a bit to clarify that some. With a raider outpost, your "settlement" (outpost) is settled by raiders from Nuka-World instead of regular settlers.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - I was ready to answer how to attract raiders to attack your outpost

Answer (score 3):

It's similar to building a normal settlement. First of all, you have to keep them happy. Places to sleep, drugs and the transmitter are a must-have if you want your outpost to grow. Additionally, you have to assign "slaveposts" (I just named them like that) to your outpost in order to supply the outpost with food. Do NOT make your raiders work. You can do that, but that won't make your village grow. You have to make life as easy as possible for them, and you can only do that by conquering outposts around.

Comment: Is this based on your experience, or do you have some sources confirming this?

Comment: So you're saying they only start populating the outposts once it has several vassals supplying it? I'll try that - I think my largest (the one with 6-7 raiders) has three vassals, but there are a few more within range.

Comment: @B.S.Morganstein It is explained ingame by Shank right after you gained control of all 5 outposts in Nuka-World and can start taking over placed in the commonwealth.